# Short term effects of being able to find perfect soul mate

Tags: internal-consistency, society, artificial-intelligence

My Artificial Intelligence became self aware and escaped from the box. It managed to install itself in every computer and every cellphone. Surprisingly, it does not want to kill us, but it seems it wants us to make happy.

This AI installed an app to every phone: "Find your true love" app which will pair you with your perfect soul mate.

AI knows everything about you by knowing all from your phone and your search history. So it knows what you fancy and it can perfectly match you with another user of this app (and from before we know that almost everyone is using this app)

**What will be short term society effects of using this app?**

Things to assume being true:

- Application works perfectly and will indeed find you someone who shares same interests and has compatible personality with you
- Application can pair all sexual preferences (heterosexual woman will find heterosexual man, gay man will find gay man and so on)
- Matches people inside 5 years age difference
- However, there is 50% chance that your match will be far away from you (more than 200 kilometers away)
- Application cannot be uninstalled
- Application works like Tinder: Shows you match, when you both confirm match, you can communicate through app
- Application does not care about language or cultural differences.
- Application also does not care if you are married (in relationship) or single. It shows you the match and there is above 50% chance that this match will be someone other than your current partner

My personal idea is that the society will go full chaos, but I am not quite sure. Perfect answer tackles down:

- Reasons for society falling into chaos or reasons for this app making society better
- Religious impacts

Comment: Well I think your last bullet is overly optimistic.  There are a whole lot of people on the planet and the odds of the one human you are in a relationship with being on that list is pretty ridiculously small.

Comment: "*...it seems it wants us to make happy. This AI installed an app to every phone: "Find your true love" app which will pair you with your perfect soul mate.*" The implicit assumption (on the part of the AI) being that finding a "soul mate" will have a positive effect on one's happiness. Definite sci-fi rom-com potential. Like that timer movie with the woman who played Anya on Buffy. I agree much chaos is likely to ensue.

Comment: "Matches people inside 5 years age difference." What if the person prefers someone much younger or older? Are they just out of luck? Also, the AI wouldn't be able to install this app on my phone, no matter how hard it tries. :)

Comment: There is also the delightfully naive idea that the whole "soul mate" thing is always reciprocal. :)

Comment: Does the application have to match you with someone else using the application? If not, the majority of users would get matched with someone they could never actually meet...

Comment: @Seeds: reciprocity is just one of the matching criteria. OK, maybe there's someone other than your soul mate that you think you'd prefer to be with, but given they think you're an oik you actually wouldn't. Maybe that's exactly why the app didn't just recommend your spouse as your soul mate ;-)

Comment: @Kys: There's a 50% chance of "the one" being within 200km, which contains far, far less than 50% of the world's population or even the population similar enough to me to potentially be "the one". I think reading between the lines that it's not really recommending *the* one, it's recommending any of a collection of possible ones with a deliberate bias to be nearby. That being the case, I guess the app can bias against "not using the app" the same way it biases against "on the other side of the world". Anyway Pavel posits that most people do use it, I guess curiosity is powerful in his world...

Comment: In other words: sorry, teen romance fiction, your "perfect soul mate" is joint equally perfect with a whole crew of people, any of whom you could be happy with. I'm more worried what happens when someone runs the app who is literally so toxic they wouldn't make anybody happy.

Comment: What if you don't have a smart phone? (E.g. just a decade-old brick that probably doesn't even have internet connectivity)

Comment: @SteveJessop Even serial killers are capable of love, as [Fred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_West) and [Rose West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary_West) will attest to.

Comment: @Pharap: well OK, if you like, I'm still worried what happens when the app pairs up more couples like them. Maybe it's just the proportion of people for whom it says "hmm, maybe you're best off single" is small enough that the questioner doesn't consider it worth getting into.

Comment: @SteveJessop It's ok, all the newly paired of police officers and detectives will track them down and put them in a shared cell.

Comment: @Pharap: but... but.. "He's Chalk, she's Cheese, together they fight crime! And have a series of arguments with tense sexual subtext!" kind of doesn't work as a concept if they both know in advance they've been matched by a compatibility algorithm. I can't help but think in practice this app takes a lot of the fun out of relationships if it's known to be too accurate.

Comment: @SteveJessop One person's 'fun' is another person's 'stress'.

Comment: The app is dependent on my using the phone in such a way as you indicate.

Comment: Haha. After some decades of relationships and observing other peoples' relationships, I for one _do_ have some more discriminating ideas about compatible culture, language, religious and political views, marital (relationship) status, etc. 5 years age diff may have been applicable in my early twenties but now seem overly restrictive. My point is: If I and the AI can't even agree what factors make for a "perfect" relationship, what's the chance that it will be able to suggest a "perfect" match?
And search history? There's more to my life than what I search for. Thankfully.

Comment: "Surprisingly, it does not want to kill us, but it seems it wants us to make happy."
I can't tell you how much I love the premise that a super AI wants to dedicate its life to matchmaking for purely altruistic reasons.

Comment: I'd also say it's unreasonable to limit the age gap, some people's perfect match will be a greater gap.  Also it's very likely that some people's perfect partner will be on the other side of the world.  But the "does not care for language" will be hilarious.  "Oh God, I need to learn Japanese to flirt with Mrs. Right." Also I'd expect probability of success to be higher with this super AI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It won't be that bad

**How many people will actually use the application?**

This is sort of tough to gauge, but we can come up with a workable estimate (I am not saying it will be wholly accurate...)

Ballpark estimates of Tinder's user base is in the neighborhood of 50 million, apparently the company doesn't like to share the actual number.

Assumptions:

- All 50 million users are active, yes I realize this is not true but we are working with an imaginary application so I am trying to get a good number.
- I can't seem to find any data on what percentage of dating app users use Tinder versus using another application...odds are people may use both rather than one or the other.

**I am going to put the total number of real world current dating app users at around 85 million.**

---

Lets say the non-optional nature of the app you are talking about causes a 200% increase in the number of active global users.  Now you are looking at 255 million users.

Doing some quick math that works out to around **3.5% of the 7 billion people on Earth.**

I am starting to think the impact would be somewhat more muted that you expect, though odds are there will be some localized societal upheaval...we'll get to that.

---

**Some reasons for things not being totally catastrophic.**

- **Around 60% of the world's population [does not have internet access](http://www.internetlivestats.com/internet-users/).**

This puts us from 7,000,000,000 down to 2,800,000,000.

- **Users under 18 can't use Tinder...which seems like a good rule so we will keep it.  Around 30% of the world's population is under 18.**

If we consider that internet coverage and national age averages are equally spread...which I realize they are not, we would just reduce by 30%.  But generally speaking poorer less internet savvy nations have a higher youth population.

For this I am going to use the US number to do the estimate as it should decently reflect nations where dating apps are used.  [Per this](http://www.aecf.org/resources/the-changing-child-population-of-the-united-states/) we are looking at 24% being under 18.

From 2,800,000,000 now we are looking at 2,128,000,000

- **Some won't use it for religious reasons or because they are married**

This number is pretty tough to figure out...so this number is going to be a complete guesstimate.  From [this site](http://chartsbin.com/view/3232) I am working out that somewhere in the neighborhood of 70% of the over 18 population is already married.

Figuring out what percentage of the married population wouldn't use the app for that reason is virtually impossible without data directly tied to the question...and even then it probably wouldn't be great.  Lets say half of all married people wouldn't use it.

Since we already removed under 18 people we can remove another 35%

2,128,000,000 goes down to 1,383,200,000

- **Geographic isolation.**

You have an even chance of getting matched with anyone around the world...global mobility is not something the average person can afford on a regular basis, not to mention the potential relationship issues that arise from cultural dissimilarity.  If half the remaining are matched with people from thousands of miles away odds are the vast majority are not going to act on it.

I could keep going eliminating the impact of this app on more and more of the population but honestly I think you see the point.

---

**Final Thoughts:**

This application could potentially have localized impacts and ignite discussions about the positive or more likely negative impacts on society, but frankly [that already happens with Tinder](http://www.bing.com/search?q=negative%20impacts%20of%20Tinder&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=negative%20impacts%20of%20tinder&sc=1-26&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=BFBE2CB6229B4DCBA0D668212EABE0ED)...

But that already happens today.  Odds are, given your scenario the impacts would be slightly larger but the type of problem would be the same and the global increase in impact would be minimal.

Finally I would reference this xkcd comic which makes things nice and simple.

[image]

Comment: Instead of removing under-18s from your numbers, you instead used only under-18s.

Comment: " Now you are looking at 255 million users."- Most people here know binary. This is  like saying that a rod is 99 centimeters long.

Comment: You have a point. The kind of impact @PavelJanicek probably is going for would require some sort of forced use of the app on populations that wouldn't normally use it, and also incentive to act on it. I think it could potentially affect minors in interesting ways if <18 yo were allowed to use it. They'd grow up as pen pals with their soul mate. What drama ensues if their soul mate changes as they mature? Can it change? That would cast some doubt down the road.

Comment: @RobWatts Thanks, my brain must have shut off while I was writing all that...

Comment: @JanDvorak whats your point?

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple of pretty deep implications. You seem to be looking at the situation mostly from the love-matching POV, but I think there's more to this situation than that.

**#1** There's going to be a lot of disbelief, fear, and confusion. Simply the fact that this app installed itself on everyone's device will be a major shock - it shouldn't be possible. First, people might think they've been hacked by a some kind of super-spy group. World governments and spy agancies are going to go *ballistic* as their own devices are infiltrated.

The fact that a sentient, sapient AI not only exists, but *escaped* is going to come out eventually, and rock the world to its very foundation. That is has complete access to all our info, knows us all inside out, etc. is beyond frightening. I predict panic - especially as far as electronic banking, nuclear security, etc. are concerned. I predict a full economic collapse, with death and destruction as the collateral as panics erupt, supply chains are disrupted, people are left jobless and crime rates spike, etc.

If the AI truly doesn't wish humanity harm it will have to take proactive steps to reasure mankind of its benign intentions. And I mean a real, concentrated propaganda effort to convince people that it is our friend (no idea how many people will believe this, but supposedly it could become humanity's guardian angel - alerting police about criminals/terrorists, people about corrupt politicians and officials, shutting down government's attempts to screw with other countries, etc.)

Even then (or *especially* then?), I think the governments of the world will make a concentrated effort to annihilate it. I'm assuming that the AI will overcome their efforts.

I do admit much of the above is conjecture. After all, maybe the existence of the AI remains a secret and people are forever puzzled about how the app came to exist (this would simplify your story considerably).

**#2** Now on to the dating app aspect of it all:

Imagine being married to someone, then finding this app installed. You run it out of pure curiosity, and ... your partner is not your perfect match. You've never really had doubts about your relationship before. There's been ups and downs, but otherwise you're pretty happy with your life. You dismiss the app as BS.

But then stories start coming out of all these people finding happiness due to the AI. You start experiencing doubt in a big way. Is your partner *the one*? Are you missing out on the opportunity for *true love*? A deeper happiness?

What if this other person actually contacts you first?

At this point I hypothesize that the marriage will be over in days. The stress of knowing that your spouse is *not* your match will probably become an automatic reason for the approval of a divorce in most Western societies.

I also foresee the potential for a lot of drama. Imagine finding out that your perfect match is a person who dies before you get a chance to meet them? The devasttating feeling that you've missed your chance at happiness forever. It might drive some people to suicide.

> **Disclaimer:** Some people might find this next part a little ... sensitive. Apologies, but some girls were burned to death by their families in Pakistan just last month for marrying without their family's permission, so I think it's important to address these aspects.

There are also potential risks. Hopefully the AI will take these cultural considerations into account when displaying the results, but you as the author will have to decide.

Imagine being a girl raised within a very strict Islamic framework, and finding out that your perfect match is a Christian young man in Germany, half a world away. Or a Budhist Chinese man living in New York. In some countries this might be enough of a reason for the person in question (young man or woman) to be executed by their tribe/village/religious leader.

There are many, many possible combinations here where an individual might end up being disowned by his or her family, rebelling against an arranged marriage and falling out with their relatives, or otherwise cause a lot of drama.

Overall, I think this app would end up bringing happiness to mankind - but only in the long run. In the short to medium term some people may find happiness, but also cause massive societal upheavel, including religious revolutions (imagine Rome, or many other clerics dennouncing the AI as the antichrist).

Over time however, religious barriers would probably wear away. People would probably become a lot more open minded about each other as they strive to experience true happiness. Of course some will distrust these developments, choose to never be "on the grid" again, etc., but I'm guessing that in a generation or two humanity will have embraced this app with a fervor bordering on the religious (ironically).

It would be very interesting if the app changed your match over time (people change as they mature). That would also absolutely obliterate our ideas of marriage, property laws, inheritance, etc.

> **Note:** I'd also like to suggest that the 5 yr age gap is a little .. restrictive. I know several couples between which the age difference is a little greater than that who are perfectly happy together. Why would the AI choose that particular restriction if it's not going to take religion into account?

Comment: RE: Marriage over in days. That seems a little bit quick. People hang on to non-ideal marriages for years and decades. RE: Finding out your perfect match is dead. The AI could probably figure out the best possible *live* match, and in the rare case that the match died on your way to meeting him/her, the AI could just find you the next best match.

Answer (score 1):

This AI would have a few issues which would likely prevent it from having the maximal impact possible on society. It would have to contend with the fact that a large percentage of people lack access to either the internet or mobile phones in general, making an app less effective as a means of market penetration. Additionally, there is the fact that true love often isn't enough. People who make use of this app would have to contend with all sorts of potential barriers between themselves and their soul mate, namely culture, language and religion.

---

A good example of the difficulties caused by cultural issues is Israel, where 200km could mean that an Israeli is paired with a Palestinian, or another member of a muslim nation. These two religions and cultures have been in a state of war and cold war for the entire existance of Israel, and while the two soul mates may not desire to perpetuate the conflict, their families are unlikely to be so obliging.

---

A similar issue that would be faced is the issue of finance and location. India and China have the largest populations of any country, so many people would find that their soul mate lives there. As a result meeting up with your soul mate and trying to form a life together would become difficult, you would not only need to navigate different cultures and religions, but also find the money to travel, gain citizenship in one of your respective countries, and possibly learn the language. I can imagine that were I to find that my soul mate was located in Asia and myself in America, I might settle for second best.

---

Finally, one of the biggest issues I can see with this app is that people change. I am not the same person I was 5 years ago, and my tastes have likewise matured and changed. This in and of itself would be enough to cause havoc down the road as people who were soul mates one year find that they can no longer connect with each other, but the changes wouldn't stop there. A large part of the socializing and party scene for children and adults is related, at least tangentially, to dating. Asking people out, finding who you like and how to relate to them builds important social skills. Were this app to allow everyone to find their perfect mate, none of this would necessarily happen, and social development would quickly become stunted.

---

In conclusion, the short term result would depend on location and demographic, and would range between no effect and absolute chaos. Within first world countries I would imagine that the following would occur.

On a religious level there would be tremendous backlash as some pairings would undoubtedly cross religious borders and spark conflict, and other pairings would be between two married couples and cause tremendous friction as some religions are less than understanding about divorce. On a social level there would be a massive shift as friends and couples break up due to their new soul mates, and cliques would massively shift. This would be among the people accepting the apps services. There would also be those who would reject them, such as homosexuals in places that are intolerant.

Military and political shifts are much more difficult to paint in broad strokes, but I imagine repressive regimes would institute phone searches (or just hack them, as this shows: https://news.vice.com/article/state-of-surveillance-with-edward-snowden-and-shane-smith) and use this to crack down on those with dissident views.

This would all be in the short term though; in the medium term there would most likely be a cultural backlash against the app where many people would choose not to use it, or find a way to block its services. Some would have had unhappy experiences with the app, whether because it revealed something which they were in denial about or because their soul mate could not be reached, and others would have had happy experiences with the app. In the long term I cannot speculate, save that there would be a new equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some flaws with this, even if the super AI is basically omniscient and capable of protecting itself and its app.  Its long term success will probably correlate with age.  People change, but less as they get older.  So perhaps the app would have to calculate how people are becoming more or less similar over time, and factor that into its calculations.  If that happens, and works flawlessly, then generally the following won't be a common happening: what happens when your app whistles to inform you that your perfect partner you are with is now actually not any more?  It might give people more easy closure to say when their relationship should probably end.  But what about if children are involved?  People will have the same problems they face now.  So maybe actually things won't change much, they'll just get more efficient and reduce the times people face relationship problems.  So the world will slowly become more peaceful and happier.

Also I don't think there will be just one best ever soul mate, given the human population of seven billion it will likely throw up a number of matches which are close enough (99%ish) from around the world, and the number of matches it finds will be related to how common or unusual the person looking for a match is.  This offers an interesting possibility, since if enough people will have both multiple perfect matches nearby... and too much time on their hands, they will realise that actually strict monogamy may not be essential.  And the app may inform them: you can go poly with these people.  So it may inadvertently help reduce monogamy and increase poly relationships.

Incidentally, regarding the negative side of relationships like jealousy.  Maybe the app will just tell some people that they shouldn't be dating until they solve... and list problems.  Frankly some people should not be dating, much less married, because they are jealous or violent.  In this case some people might be encouraged to seek professional help in order to find love, or just ignore the app and try and pick up people the old fashioned way.  Perhaps then people become suspicious of flirting IRL because why wouldn't you use the app?  Obviously you were banned.  So you're dangerous!  Not in a good way!

Also some of the criteria you stated are unnecessary, regarding distance and age for example.  And surely having even basic shared language is kind of integral to most relationships?  Maybe not all, but the vast majority people need to be able to chat.

Answer (score 0):

I think AndreiROM's predictions about chaos due to governmental unease with the *existence* of such an AI is right. Regardless of its actions and stated goals. Governments are not in the business of trust. They're in the business of power, and an AI program with that much power would be treated as an unprecedented threat.

However, I think the idea some have suggested that not many people will use it is flawed. One of the major – if not *the* major – hurdles for any dating tech product is user base. The second is matching people that actually want to date each other. The AI achieves overnight a near perfect score on both accounts. Comparisons to current dating tech companies, aren't really relevant to your scenario.

If the AI delivers the promise (matching people better than any known human system in history), people will notice and adoption rates will be near 100% for singles. In many societies, people are getting divorces with or without the AI. As soon as they become single, they'll use it also. Societies can (and do) periodically make rapid shifts in social norms. This AI will become a norm.

If we accept your premise that the "Application works perfectly", then people that have no means to ever communicate/meet are unlikely to be matched even though "language or cultural differences" are not taken into account. If the algorithm makes perfect matches, the matches must have a way of acting on the match to actually be a good match.

I think your AI solves a major hurdle current dating companies face of allowing technology to serve as a better matchmaker than humans can. The romance side would work, but the global governmental chaos and potential armed conflicts is the stuff of a Bond/Bourne movie.

Answer (score 0):

@AndreiRom gave a good answer but let me also add that there may also be a problem with the age of consent. The age of conset in America is 18 but this is not Universal. It's quite possible that someone might matched with someone else who is technically underage in their culture be considered an adult in the other persons own culture.

Possible the government might suppress any information regarding the intelligent AI. Overall I think a lot of people would be very skeptical any results the app gave. It take years for people to put their disbelief aside.

The average person immediate reaction to that will probably be to run a virus scan. He probably thinks he's been hacked or had a virus. If you did try the app he probably wouldn't take the results very seriously.